# Drawing the derivative of a curve

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have a 3D curve in MATLAB, now I want to draw the derivative of that curve in another graph? 
For example, for *y* = *x*<sup>2</sup> the derivative w.r.t. *x* is *y* = 2*x*.

How can I do this ?

Comment: you mean derivative? If you have symbolic toolbox, you can compute symbolic derivatives automatically for simple functions.

Comment: no, my curve is not simple. I just come a simple example!

Comment: If you want numerical differentiation (not derivation), you can simply use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation
Try using `diff`.

Answer (score 4):

I do not understand the '3D' part. Why is y=x^2 a 3D curve?

But if you want to plot y=x^2 and its derivative on the same plot, use ezplot

```
clear all; close all;
syms x 
y=x^2;
h=ezplot(y,[-6,6]);
set(h, 'Color', 'r'); 
hold on;
ezplot(diff(y,x),[-6,6]);
```

[image]